# Как скрыть параметры окна?

Tags: java, javafx

Нужно скрыть параметры окна (кнопки ЗАКРЫТЬ/СВЕРНУТЬ/РАЗВЕРНУТЬ) (JavaFX)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {
    primaryStage.initStyle( StageStyle.UNDECORATED );
    ...
}
```